# How to use -split operator while still retaining the substring used to split to the string?

Tags: powershell

Something, I thought to be straight forward is proving to be difficult.

```
 1one2two3three4four5five
```

I have a simple string like the above and want to split it, using the digits **but** still retain the digits themselves, in the new array.

The following `"1one2two3three4four4five" -split "\d"` results in:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

the digits were discarded, I am looking for something like, this:

```
1one
2two
3three
4four
5five
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a look ahead.

```
"1one2two3three4four4five" -split "(?=\d)"
```

output

```
1one
2two
3three
4four
4five
```

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called “lookaround”, are
> zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start
> and end of word anchors explained earlier in this tutorial. The
> difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then
> gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That
> is why they are called “assertions”. They do not consume characters in
> the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

taken from https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Nicely done; you'll get an extra empty array element at the start, though, which you can filter out with `-ne ''`

Comment: Or, take a slice after the array is known. `$Arr = ("1one2two3three4four4five" -split "(?=\d)"); $Arr = $Arr[1..($Arr.Length - 1)]`

Comment: `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` will get rid of that empty element.